# Why does this work with #[cfg(tests)] but not without?

Tags: rust

Recently, I've been playing with Rust and gRPC using the Tonic libraries. I started looking at how to create a custom Codec and I'm scratching my head over this...

Starting with this chunk of code, I copied the `MockEncoder` & `MockDecoder` and added all the same imports used here in the test module:
https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/tonic/src/codec/prost.rs#L133-L158

Then I got stuck on this error:

```
no method named `bytes` found for mutable reference `&mut tonic::codec::DecodeBuf<'_>` in the current scope

method not found in `&mut tonic::codec::DecodeBuf<'_>`rustc(E0599)
codec.rs(55, 37): method not found in `&mut tonic::codec::DecodeBuf<'_>`
```

The error is complaining about `let out = Vec::from(buf.bytes());` because `DecodeBuf` doesn't implement a bytes method.

Now, for some reason, if I wrap this code I copied in a module with `#[cfg(tests)]` (similar to how this originally appeared in Tonic) this error goes away. I can compile and run tests without any errors.

Curious, what is `#[cfg(tests)]` doing that makes `buf.bytes()` compile and is there something I can import in order to move MockDecoder outside of this test config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is `#[cfg(test)]` (singular), not `#[cfg(tests)]` (plural).  This is probably not failing because it's not being compiled or run at all, since the option is never set.

Comment: Facepalm, I copied that directly from Tonic and didn't notice it was plural. And it definitely doesn't work if I make it singular.

Comment: I cannot tell you how many times I have made a similar error.

Comment: Just added an issue and PR for this here: https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/pull/584